# Is there a general construction that allows us to produce groups with arbitrary automorphism group?

Tags: group-theory

In other words, given a group $G$, is there a construction that produces a group $H$ such that $Aut(H) \cong G$?

Comment: Replace $\operatorname{Aut}$ by $\operatorname{Out}$, then "yes".